# Python Queue-Like Container

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue

I would like a container to do the following in python 2-7:

I need that container to behave like a queue: first in first out, I append to it objects and then get them in the same order "from the other end".

However I also need to be able to read up to 5 objects from the beginning of the queue without popping them, then if I don't need them anymore I will pop them from the queue.

I am new to python and I need to know is there any container that would act as such? Or any easy simple implementation for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you want a `deque` from the `collections` module.  It includes (among other things) append, pop, pop_left, and rotate methods, and also supports indexing.  Indexing slows toward the middle, but is fast at the ends.

Comment: With deque I will have to popleft then appendleft, is there a container I can access through indexing like a list, and would behave like deque? I am looking for that if available it would be faster, thank you though

Comment: "and also supports indexing". for instance, my_deque[3] is the 4th element.

Answer (score 1):

See this module from the standard library. It should provide you with everything you want.

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/python/9780132778633/data-structures/ch02lev1sec5

```
import Queue

q = Queue.Queue()

for i in range(5):
    q.put(i)

while not q.empty():
    print q.get(),
print
```

Comment: I bet you could subclass `collections.deque` to do what you want.